# Need help printing uneven numbers from a list using a for loop

Tags: python, loops

Using python, I need to make a list of numbers from 3-30, and print all the uneven numbers using a for loop. Thanks

Comment: by uneven do you mean print the odd numbers? (i.e. 3,5,7,...29)

Comment: yes,sorry i meant odd numbers. Just learning from a book and I am very stuck

Answer (score 1):

You can split lists into odd or even numbers using the modulus function with 2. Even numbers (`2%2`,`4%2`, etc.) will evaluate to 0 because there is no remainder.

```
numbers = [1,10,20,30,40,50]
output=[i for i in numbers if i%2 != 0 ]
```

Oops, now reading that you want a for loop, you can:

```
numbers = [1,10,20,30,40,50]
output = [] 
for i in numbers
 if i%2 != 0
  output.append(i)
```

Comment: I am sure this would work, but this is still too advanced for me. As mentioned, I need to do it using a for loop. Any ideas using a for loop? thanks for your time.

Comment: essentially, the first approach to output is using a for loop, but it is inside of the right of the equals sign. output is equal to an array [] of only those numbers `i` in `numbers` that are odd (`i%2 !=0`)

Answer (score 0):

```
l = list(range(3, 31))
for num in l:
    if num % 2 == 1:
        print(num)
```